# About Previewing an Image in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<img [src]="imageInput" alt="" width="100%">
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept="image/*">

onChange(event: any) {
    this.imageInput = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.imageInput = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

So here is my code in angular. My problem is that every time I will upload and preview an image. There's this "GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)" that keeps on showing in my console log.

Comment: From where you are getting those image? Is it located under Asset folder?

Answer (score 1):

Initially `imageInput` is `null`, so you can get rid of the message with an `ngIf` like this:

```
<img *ngIf="imageInput" [src]="imageInput" alt="" width="100%">
```

Check it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nXanFjgkEBt12J4AW8lC?p=preview).

Comment: the problem is still there sir even if I put *ngIf there. even if there's a default image. once I change it, there's still an error.

Comment: @LordGrim Did you see the plunkr link? If you do the same, you should get the same result, unless you've done something else which you've not shared in your question.

Comment: In your onChange function in your plunkr. Why is it that there's no $event and you have "reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);".
Where is the "event" came from?

Comment: I tried removing it. but there's another error.

Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: @LordGrim Changed the plunkr, you can check it out again.

Comment: it is still not working sir. 
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. Maybe in "reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);"

Answer (score 0):

you just need to delete this line
this.imageInput = event.target.files[0];